# I am trying to run flask-migrate and am encountering some problems. It says I have 1 more then 1 database even though I have 1. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

Here is the error I am getting.

```
 C:\Users\n\.virtualenvs\flaskblog2-leL8dPgn\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:851: UserWarning: Neither SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI nor SQLALCHEMY_BINDS is set. Defaulting SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to "sqlite:///:memory:".
  warnings.warn(
C:\Users\n\.virtualenvs\flaskblog2-leL8dPgn\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:872: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  warnings.warn(FSADeprecationWarning(
```

In my code `SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS` is set to `False`.
Why am I getting the error?

Also I googled `SQLALCHEMY_BINDS`.

This means I have 2 databases.
But I only had 1 database. I have test.db. Does migrate folder also count as database?

I am following the documentation for flask and am still getting the errors. Here is the documentation.

https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Also I am getting an operational error when I try to register a user. I assume after I migrate the database I have to create the database using

```
from app import db,create_app
from app.models import User , Posts, Followers 
app = create_app()
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

is this correct?

Thanks for the help

Thanks

I followed the documentation from https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

My app looks like https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/tree/master/Python/Flask_Blog/11-Blueprints except I added the correct code from flask-migrate documentation.

Comment: The error is from SQLAlchemy, and it says that you haven't configured your database URL. Add `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` to your configuration to remove this error.

Comment: Do you think I should delete this question it was a dumb question?